# Устарела ли данная строка в HTML 5?

Tags: html, html5

Устарела ли данная строка в HTML 5?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Можно ли ее заменить `<meta charset="UTF-8">`?

Comment: а можно саму строку в студию. Пожалусто

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: вставь ее в вопрос

Comment: Поправил, теперь видно

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял ты просто указываешь кодировку, то как ты ее делал делалось в `HTML 4`  это можно сделать проще  `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: То есть это старый вариант, который был в HTML 4, верно?
Для старых браузеров, <meta charset="UTF-8"> тоже будет работать?

Comment: не думаю что тебе есть дело до настолько старых браузеров, смело пиши `<meta charset="UTF-8">`